# SAS - Selecting optimal quantities

Tags: sas

I'm trying to solve a problem in SAS where I have quantities of customers across a range of groups, and the quantities I select need to be as even across the different categories as possible.  This will be easier to explain with a small table, which is a simplification of a much larger problem I'm trying to solve.

Here is the table:

```
Customer Category | Revenue band | Churn Band | # Customers

        A                 1             1              4895
        A                 1             2               383
        A                 1             3               222
        A                 2             1                28
        A                 2             2              2828
        A                 2             3               232
        B                 1             1              4454
        B                 1             2               545
        B                 1             3               454
        B                 2             1              4534
        B                 2             2               434
        B                 2             3               454
```

Suppose I need to select 3000 customers from category A, and 3000 customers from category B.  From the second category, within each A and B, I need to select an equal amount from 1 and 2.  If possible, I need to select a proportional amount across each 1, 2, and 3 subcategories.  Is there an elegant solution to this problem?  I'm relatively new to SAS and so far I've investigated OPTMODEL, but the examples are either too simple or too advanced to be much use to me yet.

Edit:  I've thought about using survey select.  I can use this to select equal sizes across the Revenue Bands 1, 2, and 3.  However where I'm lacking customers in the individual churn bands, surveyselect may not select the maximum number of customers available where those numbers are low, and I'm back to manually selecting customers.

Comment: If you want an equal number from each group you need to look at how many people are in the smallest group and then choose that many people from the others. Or maybe you mean something else by "select an equal number". What are your column headings?

Comment: The headings are - Customer Type, Revenue Band (1 for $1000, 2 for $2000), and Churn Band (1 for 0-500, 2 for 500-1000, 3 for 1000+).  In this problem I may be lacking sufficient customers, and I will need to select all (for example A,2,1 is only 28).  I'll need to select more from the other categories to satisfy the constraint of A summing to 3000 and B summing to 3000. Because A,2,1 is lacking I would select more from A,1,1 which is 4895.

Comment: Interesting. If you can write down an objective function -- which basically has to penalize solutions with unequal distributions of people -- perhaps you could use a genetic algorithm via PROC GA.

Comment: Maybe SURVEYSELECT with SIZE?

Comment: Add the column headings into the question via edit rather than the comments please. You've only listed 3 columns and display 4.

Comment: @user1475246 ...  an you please provide dataset that you have for this question, i also want to conduct and learn " customer churn rate prediction " but i dont have dataset to carry on my analysis. Please help me by sharing your data-link or ask for my email. Thanking you in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are still some ambiguities in the problem statement, but I hope that the PROC OPTMODEL code below is a good start for you. I tried to add examples of many different features, so that you can toy around with the model and hopefully get closer to what you actually need.

Of the many things you could optimize, I am minimizing the maximum violation from your "If possible" goal, e.g.:

```
min MaxMismatch = MaxChurnMismatch;
```

I was able to model your constraints as a Linear Program, which means that it should scale very well. You probably have other constraints you did not mention, but that would probably beyond the scope of this site.

With the data you posted, you can see from the output of the `print` statements that the optimal penalty corresponds to choosing 1500 customers from `A,1,1`, where the ideal would be 1736. This is more expensive than ignoring the customers from several groups:

```
[1] ChooseByCat 
 A     3000 
 B     3000 

[1] [2] [3] Choose IdealProportion 
 A    1  1   1500      1736.670 
 A    1  2      0       135.882 
 A    1  3      0        78.762 
 A    2  1     28         9.934 
 A    2  2   1240      1003.330 
 A    2  3    232        82.310 
 B    1  1   1500      1580.210 
 B    1  2      0       193.358 
 B    1  3      0       161.072 
 B    2  1   1500      1608.593 
 B    2  2      0       153.976 
 B    2  3      0       161.072 

Proportion MaxChurnMisMatch 
  0.35478       236.67
```

That is probably not the ideal solution, but figuring how to model exactly your requirements would not be as useful for this site. You can contact me offline if that is relevant.

I've added quotes from your problem statement as comments in the code below.

Have fun!

```
data custCounts;
    input cat $ rev churn n;
datalines;
        A                 1             1              4895
        A                 1             2               383
        A                 1             3               222
        A                 2             1                28
        A                 2             2              2828
        A                 2             3               232
        B                 1             1              4454
        B                 1             2               545
        B                 1             3               454
        B                 2             1              4534
        B                 2             2               434
        B                 2             3               454
;

proc optmodel printlevel = 0;
    set CATxREVxCHURN init {} inter {<'A',1,1>};
    set CAT = setof{<c,r,ch> in CATxREVxCHURN} c; 

    num n{CATxREVxCHURN};
    read data custCounts into CATxREVxCHURN=[cat rev churn] n;
    put n[*]=;

    var Choose{<c,r,ch> in CATxREVxCHURN} >= 0 <= n[c,r,ch]
      , MaxChurnMisMatch >= 0, Proportion >= 0 <= 1
    ;

    /* From OP:
       Suppose I need to select 3000 customers from category A, 
       and 3000 customers from category B. */
    num goal = 3000;
    /* See "implicit slice" for the parenthesis notation, i.e. (c) below. */
    impvar ChooseByCat{c in CAT} = 
        sum{<(c),r,ch> in CATxREVxCHURN} Choose[c,r,ch];
    con MatchCatGoal{c in CAT}:
        ChooseByCat[c] = goal;

    /* From OP:
       From the second category, within each A and B, 
       I need to select an equal amount from 1 and 2 */
    con MatchRevenueGroupsWithinCat{c in CAT}:
        sum{<(c),(1),ch> in CATxREVxCHURN} Choose[c,1,ch]
      = sum{<(c),(2),ch> in CATxREVxCHURN} Choose[c,2,ch]
    ;

    /* From OP: 
       If possible, I need to select a proportional amount 
       across each 1, 2, and 3 subcategories. */
    con MatchBandProportion{<c,r,ch> in CATxREVxCHURN, sign in / 1 -1 /}:
        MaxChurnMismatch >= sign * ( Choose[c,r,ch] - Proportion * n[c,r,ch] );

    min MaxMismatch = MaxChurnMismatch;

    solve;

    print ChooseByCat;
    impvar IdealProportion{<c,r,ch> in CATxREVxCHURN} = Proportion * n[c,r,ch];
    print Choose IdealProportion;
    print Proportion MaxChurnMismatch;

quit;
```